# Linux rename function not being used correctly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, unix

I'm trying to use the rename command in a Terminal in Ubuntu to append a string to the beginning of some avi file names as follows.

```
rename -n 's/(\w)\.avi$/String_to_add__$1\.avi/' *.avi
```

So I expect the following:

```
String_to_add_MyMovie.avi
```

Problem is that when I run the command it appends the string to the end of the file name, so I end up with the following:

```
MyMovie_String_to_add_.avi
```

I'm not sure if I have the perlexpr syntax wrong or something else.  Any insight is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Thanks for the suggestions, I tried the suggestions from alno and plundra and made the following modification:

```
rename -n 's/(\w+)\.avi$/String_to_add__$1\.avi/' *.avi
```

But now the file gets the string inserted in the middle of the name as follows:

My_String_to_add_Movie

My apologies though, I neglected to mention that the titles are preceded by 3 numeric values, so the file name nomenclature is  `{3 numbers}-My_Movie.avi` so for example `001-My_Movie.avi`.  But I didn't think this would make a difference since I'm assuming `\w+` matches alphanumeric characters, might the '-' be the issue?

Haven't tried Christian's approach yet, I want to be able to use the rename command, or at least understand why it's not working before I try a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think rename -n is standard. You could do this:

```
for i in *.avi; do mv $i String_to_add_$i; done
```

Comment: For a simple thing like prepending a string to a filename, this is the obvious way, yes. Although you want to quote (`"$i"`) your source and target.

Comment: As for being standard, I guess he is using Debian or Ubuntu, with the `rename`-alternative pointing to `prename` (as in perl rename), which comes with the package `perl`. So I would *think* it is pretty common on Debian-like systems, although I would use `prename` instead of relying on an alternative being set correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're only matching a single character with `\w`, you want `\w+`, so the complete line would be:

```
rename -n 's/(\w+)\.avi$/String_to_add__$1\.avi/' *.avi
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct version:

```
rename -n 's/(\w+)\.avi$/String_to_add__$1\.avi/' *.avi
```

You simply forgot + after \w, so it tried to match only one character.